# How to check stream has data or not in Snowflake DAGs with python API?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created Snowflake tasks and DAGs with Python. Those task queries are keep running if streams doesn't have data also, I need to check stream has data or not. If the stream has data then only the task should run. In Snowflake DAGs, how to check stream has data or not?

```
def test(database,schema_env,warehouse,prod_config,root):
    dag = DAG("TESTDAG", schedule=timedelta(minutes=1), warehouse=warehouse)


    with dag:
       
        STREAM_TO_INTERMEDIATE = DAGTask(test_config["PARENT_TASK_NAME"], test_config["PROD_PARENT_TASK"],
                                             warehouse=warehouse)
        INTERMEDIATE_TO_STAGE = DAGTask(test_config["CHILD_TASK_NAME"],
                                                    test_config["CHILD_TASK"],
                                                    warehouse=warehouse)

        INTERMEDIATE_TO_STAGE >> STREAM_TO_INTERMEDIATE  
        schema = root.databases[database].schemas[schema_env]
        dag_op = DAGOperation(schema)
        dag_op.deploy(dag)
```

Before `STREAM_TO_INTERMEDIATE` task, I want to check stream has data or not.

PARENT_TASK:

INSERT INTO TEST_INTERMEDIATE (ID,NAME,LASTUPDATED_TIMESTAMP,INGESTION_TIME,TOPIC) SELECT ID,NAME,current_timestamp() AS LASTUPDATED_TIMESTAMP,CreateTime as INGESTION_TIME,topic as TOPIC FROM TEST_STREAM

In snowflake DAGs parameters only, we are calling parent_task using python API. Here how to use WHEN SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA in snowflake DAG. In normal task WHEN SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA is working fine. IN Snowflake DAG with python API SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA is not working

Please find below example:

dag = DAG("TEMP_DAG", schedule=timedelta(minutes=1), warehouse="TEST_WH")

```
CONNECTION_PARAMETERS = {"account": "XXX", "user": "YYY",
                             "password": "", "warehouse":"TEST_WH",
                             "database": "TEST_DB", "schema": "TEST_SCHEMA"}

connection = connect(**CONNECTION_PARAMETERS)
root = Root(connection)

with dag:
   

    test_parent_task = DAGTask("TEST_PARENT_TASK", """INSERT INTO TEST_INTERMEDIATE(ID,NAME,LASTUPDATED_TIMESTAMP,INGESTION_TIME,TOPIC)
        SELECT ID ,NAME,
          current_timestamp(),
          RECORD_INGESTION_TIME,
          TOPIC
        FROM TEST_DB.TEST_SCHEMA.TEST_STREAM;"""

    # Create a task by using SQL
    test_child_task = DAGTask("TEST_CHILD_TASK",
                        definition="call DUMMY_PROC()", warehouse="TEST_WH")

    test_child_task >> test_parent_task 
    schema = root.databases["TEST_DB"].schemas["TEST_SCHEMA"]
    dag_op = DAGOperation(schema)
    dag_op.deploy(dag)
```

I wanted to check WHEN SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA("TEST_STREAM") before running test_parent_task in python API.

Comment: Can you use the "WHEN SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA ...." statement when you create each task?

Comment: PARENT_TASK:
INSERT INTO TEST_INTERMEDIATE (ID,NAME,LASTUPDATED_TIMESTAMP,INGESTION_TIME,TOPIC)
 SELECT ID,NAME,current_timestamp(),CreateTime as INGESTION_TIME,topic as TOPIC  FROM TEST_STREAM 

the above one is my task.In DAGs parameters only we are calling parent_task using python API.here how to use WHEN SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA in snowflake DAG.

In normal task WHEN SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA is working fine. IN Snowflake DAG with python API SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA is not working

Comment: Please don’t add additional information/questions in comments. Update your question so that it reflects the current situation

Comment: Isn't what you want documented here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-python-api/reference/latest/_autosummary/snowflake.core.task.Task#snowflake.core.task.Task.condition

Comment: I tried to add WHEN SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS DATA in DAGTASK in python API,its not worked. Can you share example?

Comment: Sorry - I've never tried this, I just read the documentation